# Linux HA vs Apache Hadoop

Tags: linux, hadoop, hadoop2

I'm using Cloudera (Apache Hadoop), so I have a pretty good idea about it.

However, I just found out about Linux HA project and 
I cannot find out what is **the difference between Linux HA and Apache Hadoop**.

**When should we use Apache Hadoop and when should we use Linux HA?**

Thank you!

Comment: HA is a feature of Apache Hadoop cluster when running MR jobs on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux HA is a software based High-availability cluster services which are used to improve the ability of many kinds of services. That means - This Linux HA is used to keep desired services up and running with no downtime. This uses the concept of heartbeat to identify the service state in the cluster. For example if you have a web server running on hostA, it is replicated to run on hostB also. Whenever the hostA is down, hostB starts and serves requests. i.e there is no downtime provided by the server.

Whereas, Apache Hadoop is a Framework that solves the problem of storing large amount of data and processing it.